# Excel Matching rows in two Worksheets and filling in the blank row

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 worksheets, "Yellow" and "Green".

Yellow:
[image]

Green:
[image]

My column headers are "Description", "Date Created", "Quantity", "Unit Price", and "Vendor #".
The "Description" column in the Green sheet doesn't contain any information. 
I want Excel to go one row at a time down the Green sheet and fill in the Description from the Yellow sheet only if ALL FOUR of the other columns ("Date Created", "Quantity", "Unit Price", and "Vendor #") match on both sheets in that row.
There are a different number of rows on both sheets (about 4,000) and more columns on Green than on Yellow (which is why I need the "Description" on the Green sheet too).
I have looked into vlookup, and Index/Match. But neither worked. 
I found this code but it is calculating and I have nothing to calculate. This code returned the Column Header in the first column ("Description").

```
{=INDEX(Yellow!B:B,MATCH(1,(C:C=Yellow!C:C)*(D:D=Yellow!D:D)*(E:E=Yellow!E:E)*(F:F=Yellow!F:F),0))}
```

I thought I would try winging it on my own and came up with this:

```
{=INDEX(Yellow!B2:F2875,MATCH(1,(C3=Yellow!B2:F2875)*(D3=Yellow!B2:F2875)*(E3=Yellow!B2:F2875)*(F3=Yellow!B2:F2875),0),1}
```

That returns "#N/A"

I think I might need an IF statement somewhere since I only want "Description" to fill in if all four of the other columns match.

Comment: You need to make all the `Yellow!B2:F2875` ranges into single column ranges.  So `(C3=Yellow!C2:C2875)*(D3=Yellow!D2:D2875)*...` and so on.  Also I believe this is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode.

Comment: Oh and you will need to make all the references absolute: `(C3=Yellow!$C$2:$C$2875)*(D3=Yellow!$D$2:$D$2875)*...` and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use vba, nor if. Create a new column on the left hand side of both tables. Concatenate row by row "Date Created", "Quantity", "Unit Price", and "Vendor #" columns with a formula into the new columns, but place a separator character between the fields. You can use vlookup to get the description from yellow tab.